# Fuzzy matching on keyword in a larger string - SAS

Tags: sas, substring, proc-sql, fuzzy-comparison

Using SAS, I have a table with sentences and I am looking to find the rows in the table where the keyword is found in the sentence making use of fuzzy matching (`complev function`). Is there a way in SAS to find the keyword string in the sentences? I know how to use `complev`, but I only can use it to compare complete strings, not a string as a part of a larger string. For this example table the keyword would be `'example'` and the result of the comparison would be in the column `Result`. 
Thanks for your ideas!

```
This is an Example sentence : 1
Here is another one : 0
Also an exmple : 1
The examples keep coming : 1
No worries : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use this as a template. I compare the Complev value to three, but you can set it to any fitting value.

```
data have;
input string $ 1-25;
datalines;
Example sentence         
Here is another one      
Also an exmple           
The examples keep coming 
No worries               
;

data want;
   set have;
   result = 0;
   do _N_ = 1 to countw(string);
      if complev('example', scan(string, _N_)) < 3 then do;
         result=1; leave;
      end;
   end;
run;
```

EDIT: Use `complev('example', scan(string, _N_), 'i')` if you want the comparison the be case insensitive.

Comment: Is it worth standardizing the case (upper/lower) or does `complev()` account for that already?

Comment: Good catch Reeza, thank you! I thought it did, but browsing the doc, I was wrong. I edited the answer..